# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, exception

In my Web Project I am Parsing the Date selected in the Date Picker and comparing it with the Date fetched from Database till Yesterday it was working fine but from today morning it throws the **Format Exception** what could be the Problem,

My code is,

```
  try
        {
            ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(frmtxtdt.Text); // Exception Thrown here
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(frmtxtdt.Text);
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
            DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
            string frtxt = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", dt);
            string totxt = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", dt1);
            DataSet ds = Namespace.SP.Storedprocedure(frtxt,totxt).GetDataSet();

            if (!IsPageRefresh)
           {
               if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
               {
                   if(frtxt == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString()
                   && totxt == ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString())
                   {

                          ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Passkeys";

                          ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/XML/Passkeys.xml"));
                          string filename = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Pkey_rpt.rpt");

                          rpt.Load(filename);
                          rpt.SetDataSource(ds);

                          rpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Passkeys - " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString());
                    }

            }
            else if(frmtxtdt.Text.Trim() !=null && totxtdt.Text.Trim()!=null)
            {
                if (frtxt == String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", date)
                    && totxt == String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", date1) 
                    && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {

                   ClientMessaging( "Pass Key(s) Not Yet Delivered for the Selected Date...");

                }
                else
                {

                    ClientMessaging( "There is No Schedule for the Selected date....");
                }

            }
         }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of frmtxtdt.Text ?

Comment: What is this `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());` ? `DateTime.Today` is actually `DateTime`

Comment: In the Second Line _I had Mentioned it also_

Comment: Are you aware of any culture settings changes? Were there any?

Comment: What's in **frmtxtdt.Text** ?

Comment: @ joffrey Kern When I Pick the Date in the Calender the `frmtxtdt.Text` will be filled with eg : **13/06/2013**

Comment: Is `frmtxtdt` some form of calendar/datetime picker control? If so, it almost certainly has a property from which you can obtain the data **as** a `DateTime` value. Use that instead. And remove the `DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());` bits too. Just use `DateTime.Today` directly. In short, most of your problems are caused because you're converting perfectly good `DateTime`s to strings in the first place.

Comment: @Rajesh - that's because yesterday, the day portion of the date could resemble a month, and months can always be mistaken for days - so the code may have executed, but it was almost certainly confusing months and days.

Comment: Excuse me **nvoigt** Till Yesterday It was Parseing nicely and No Exception was Thrown from today only I am Facing the problem like the **Damien_the_Unbeliver** said `frmtxtdt.Text` is a Calender Picker Control which returns the data as a DateTime value

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever So you say that it may work for the Period of **01 to 12** dates of a Month

Comment: @Rajesh - yes, and further, it's probably been swapping the day and month numbers around.

Comment: @ Damien Yes It is doing like that only I used `CultureInfo GBCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");`, `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(frmtxtdt.Text, GBCultureInfo);` which tells about the International Culture Info of Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be explicit on the CultureInfo, based on the date format you're expecting to parse

```
CultureInfo GBCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); // dd/MM/YYYY
// CultureInfo USCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // MM/dd/YYYY

dt = DateTime.Parse(frmtxtdt.Text,GBCultureInfo);
```

Comment: @Rajesh As far as I know, "es-ES" represents Spanish. But there is no problem as long as the date format in that culture is what you expect your date format to be in DateTime.Parse. Note that you are using the CultureInfo object you created as a parameter to DateTime.Parse. It is not going to change anything else in the rest of your code (unless you pass it explicitly). CultureInfo controls other things (e.g. the separator for decimal numbers) but DateTime.Parse is only concerned about the date format, so any CultureInfo with the date format you need will work.

Comment: @ Paolo Falabella
 In the MSDN site it was mentioned as  
`// Creates and initializes the CultureInfo which uses the international sort. 
      CultureInfo myCIintl = new CultureInfo("es-ES", false);` so that I used "es-ES" Now again I changed to "en-GB"

Answer (score 3):

Today is the **13th** of June 2013. It was probably working before because the day was 12 or less. You need to ensure the format of the date coming from the picker is the same as the format expected when parsing.

Currently, it looks like it's parsing the day as the month.

Answer (score 1):

try like this,place code

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");//you can change to any country 
  ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
```